# How can I place images or icons inside image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I put small images or icons inside a big image? that is responsive also. 
I am planning to make a floor plan (the big image) inside of our system and when I hover the computers(small images/icons) will hover something. Any suggestion will do thank you :))

Comment: Make that big image as background of a `div` and place those icons inside that. Something like 
`<div id="floor">
    <img class="icon">
    <img class="icon">
    ...
</div>`

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#background {
  height: 50em;
  width: 50em;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200");
}

   

img{
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <h1>Some text and another image in my big image!</h1>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
</div>
```